# Javascript switch statement- very simple, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm sure there must be a really simple answer to this, but at the risk of sounding stupid- I can't get this switch statement to work. The input var, 'status' can be either 'public' or 'draft', and I can assure you it is only holding one of those two values as I have alerted it out at various stages, and anyway, the if statement here works. Take a look:

```
        function switch_status(status){
            if (status == 'public'){
                return false;
            } if (status == 'draft') {
                return true;
            }
```

^This works, but replacing the 'if' with this 'switch' statement below doesn't work.

```
            switch(status){
            case 'public':
                return false;
            case 'draft':
                return true;
            }
        }
```

The first one to provide me with the inevitable embarrassingly simple answer wins my accolade!

EDIT: Here is my full code-

```
        $('.status').live('click',
                function(){
                    fullClass = $(this).attr('class');
                    id = fullClass.split(' ').slice(-1);
                    status = fullClass.split(' ').slice(-2,-1);
                    var newStatus = switch_status(status);
                    alert(newStatus);
            });

        function switch_status(status){
//              if (status == 'public'){
//                  return false;
//              } if (status == 'draft') {
//                  return true;
//              }

            switch(status){
                case 'public':
                    return false;
                case 'draft':
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there an error reported when using `switch`?  Some context code may help as well - nothing posted demonstrates a problem.

Comment: Try adding a default code block after the final case -- default: return false

Comment: @g.d.d.c I've just appended the question with the full code. The alert says 'undefined', but when replacing the 'switch' with the 'if', I get the correct returned values... (!??)

Comment: @ Inrbob Thanks, I tried that, but now I'm just getting false alterted back every time (ie. the switch statement is still not identifying the two values in either of the 'cases')

Comment: Based on what I see here I would verify that `status = fullClass.split(' ').slice(-2,-1);` is working properly.  Is status a global variable that's being reused?  I see no var statements inside your live event handler.  I don't see a problem in the `switch_status` function definition at all.

Comment: @ g.d.d.c Thanks, No, status, is not a global variable, it only exists in the function. I've tried declaring all the variables there with 'var ___' and conversely without. Neither works. Baffled.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but it's a plain old JavaScript switch statement that's giving you trouble -- nothing jQuery-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `status` as an array of one string (the result of `slice`) rather than as just a string.

When you check equality between your array and your string, it appears that coercion is causing the equality check to work.  But coercion doesn't happen in a switch statement.

If I change

```
status = fullClass.split(' ').slice(-2,-1);
```

to

```
status = fullClass.split(' ').slice(-2,-1)[0];
```

then it works fine.

Comment: @ JacobM Hahaha, you dancer! THANKS! So, if I'm not straying too far outside the bounds of this question, how would you convert it to a string? (Just to wrap this up) Thanks.

Comment: As a way to teach a man to fish, here's how I found the answer: Firebug.  I stepped through the code with a watch set on status and saw that it was an array.  Firebug should always be the first tool you reach for with a javascript issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this problem is occuring due to type conversion.

Javascipt is generally a loosely typed language. The if statement you used earlier used a loose `==` comparison. This worked just fine.

However, switch statements are a different matter. For the case to be a match, the data types must match. In other words, the `status` must be converted to a string before it is passed to the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I used a .each in a jquery loop and compared value to 'this';  I could clearly see that 'this' had the correct value if I used console.log. It worked in the if/else logic but failed in the switch/case logic.

The solution is:

**var obj = this.toString();**

```
switch(obj){
    case 'one': ...
    case 'two': ...
}
```

By forcing the 'this' to a string type, the logic in the switch now works.